# TypeScript reporting Object is possibly 'undefined' when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to understand why TypeScript is giving me the following error: `Object is possibly 'undefined'`

Here's the code snippet:

```js
    const mergedDepsObj: { [key: string]: string } // Implementation here is not important

    const results: Map<string, number> = new Map();

    Object.keys(mergedDepsObj).forEach((key: string) => {
      results.has(key) ? results.set(key, results.get(key) + 1) : results.set(key, 0);
    })
```

Basically when I try to increment a value in the `Map` (results) I get that error on this line `results.set(key, results.get(key) + 1)`

It should not yelling at me since I'm checking if the value exist first.
Maybe I miss something?

Thanks,

Comment: Basically this is just a limitation of TypeScript's control flow analysis, it does not understand that after checking `has(key)` the call to `get(key)` definitely won't return `undefined`. You could use a non-null assertion: `results.get(key)! + 1`

Comment: There is no type guarding for `Map.has()` [See this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18781)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn rereading that issue reminds me that you mean [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086) instead.

Comment: @jcalz I even see that you link to it in the issue :) However Google says the one I posted was better :) since Google is always right ;)

Comment: @AaronBeall oh I see! Reading comments/answers makes it clear now. I thought I was missing something that's why my confusion. `results.get(key)! + 1` this actually works but I do really like the Custom Type guard in the below answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no type guarding for `Map.has()` [See this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18781) or [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086).

You can fix the issue by having a fallback of `0`, `-1` or whatever you think would be best for your code.

```
const mergedDepsObj: { [key: string]: string } = {}
const results: Map<string, number> = new Map();
Object.keys(mergedDepsObj).forEach((key: string) => {
  results.has(key) ? results.set(key, (results.get(key) || 0) + 1) : results.set(key, 0);
})
```

### Custom Type Guard

However, above being said, we make our own type guard with help from [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086#issuecomment-269695308).

```
interface Map<K, V> {
    // Works if there are other known strings.
    has<KnownKeys extends K, CheckedString extends K>(this: MapWith<string, V, any>, key: CheckedString): this is MapWith<K, V, CheckedString | KnownKeys>

    has<CheckedString extends K>(this: Map<string, V>, key: CheckedString): this is MapWith<K, V, CheckedString>
}

interface MapWith<K, V, DefiniteKey extends K> extends Map<K, V> {
    get(k: DefiniteKey): V;
}

const mergedDepsObj: { [key: string]: string } = {}
const results: Map<string, number> = new Map();

Object.keys(mergedDepsObj).forEach((key: string) => {
    results.has(key) ? results.set(key, results.get(key) + 1) : results.set(key, 0);
})
```

We can see it in action [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJwA4B4DSAaZANQD5kBvAKGWuQHpbkB1AeygGsBnZYGZMAC2go4UFMwHRkbEMwDuIZBzBRQAcw4A6KjX5wOuGfJwQAnlwgAPSCAAmXfMgDCghGwg2AysrXJL1u8g4xAAUAsAcAFxomIzAAlhKKiCqBIQEcCAmxARuJlHOEK7uXkmqAJRRYVzh0Rix8Q5pTi5unt7JyAA+gYYgxmbEFNrUuvoFRW2lvlYQtvYhVVHo2IlqqdlSpvktxe3llfw1Ncv1-LipBOOtJWqDAL5DoJCwiCgncWeNBAAiEDCgcQg-Wm-nmINmAWW5yIpEoNGQqggYGCbCiv3+IEB-QqRAA3BQHhQEMwQEpkABbaCImy-DAcADyACMAFZRMjIADauSiq2SAF0eXtkHdkABecgPYmksDIUQcACuABswJFagk9gQQPLyYzoKRxSAILJasEyviKEzmYUwBpchxgpSoNTaQyWWUNDBWABRRD8YIoraKPZlMWw4ayiAK5WaUbBADkNmYqjjIYA-BGoyqNBwkQGTAQ5Uqs4jkXGEHAwCnkABqZAARhDUUL0ezudyBAADGbw82s7GE0mq+ne5oc8j2xmi5oS-HE8mQ7WG8gm5Gp63x6ZO934SONLHcmnJy2x3mC6uWzODzX642j1mTxOu-i7mUgA)

Comment: This is interesting solution. It works well for literals but not for variables. 
(key1: string, key2: string)
....
if (x.has(key1)) {
  const a: string = x.get(key2); // No error, but should be!
}

Answer (score 0):

If you query for a key not in the map, you will get undefined. Not because the map holds an undefined value, but because it does not hold a value at all.

Try

results.get(key)!

Or

results.get(key) as number

Comment: OP's point is that `has(key)` should protect against your first statement. The problem is TypeScript doesn't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Becouse the compiler is not so smart to take into account behavior of Map.